# Memory Optimized Table and a disk table in another database in one transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have a SQL Transaction like this:

```
BEGIN Transaction [Trans1]
        BEGIN TRY
          Insert Into MemoryOptimizedTable
          Update [OtherDatabase].[dbo].[DiskTable]
        COMMIT TRANSACTION [Trans1]
        END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH
```

This Transaction gives this error on the update line:

> A user transaction that accesses memory optimized tables or natively
> compiled modules cannot access more than one user database or
> databases model and msdb, and it cannot write to master.

What alternatives do I have with regards to making sure both the Insert and Update statements succeed or they both fail? I mean is there an alternative to a transaction? or maybe a workaround?

Comment: With `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, the worst that could happen without a transaction is that the insert happens but the update does not (with a detectable error), at which point you can "roll back" the insert manually (client side, you may not be able to initiate a statement in the `CATCH` if the batch aborts) with a delete. Of course this is not robust in the face of hardware failure like a transaction would be, but you can't have everything. If you truly can't live with the restriction and reliability is of the utmost importance, don't use two tables across databases.

Comment: Thanks,  I rolled back the transaction in the CATCH, as you said it is not fault proof but it reduces the risk to an acceptable level.